# nutiteq,AltusMappingEngine,android,mbtiles,Mobile Atlas Creator,TileMill

Tags: android, nutiteq, mbtiles

What is the similarity and difference between "nutiteq" and "AltusMappingEngine"? I want to store map locally in my android application, for this I need to convert map to "mbtiles" format.Which tool should I use(1.Mobile Atlas Creator, or 2.TileMill) ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several MBTiles tools, result is more or less same. Choose the one depending on your source:

a) Download from online WMS or tile server -  [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net) (MOBAC)

b) Use your own vector and raster map data, and custom design - [TileMill](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/)

c) Single raster file, e.g. GeoTiff or NOAA RNC (BSB) file - [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.com/)

d) Map tile files in a directory structure: [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil)

About "nutiteq" and "AltusMappingEngine" question part:

- Altus is C-based (native), and runs on both iOs and Android. Nutiteq is currently Android Java; iOS is planned by late 2013. Advantage of Android Java is that it works also where Android NDK is not available (Android Player: e.g. BlackBerry QNX).
- pricing models are different, start level is free for both.
- Altus has more features in 2D, but (almost) no 3D. Nutiteq has 3D (2.5D views and 3D City) features.
- Altus seems to be made originally for aeronatical use cases, and has many special features for this (elevation analysis, animations, globe view). Nutiteq is made more for GIS use cases in mind (many different online/offline, vector/raster datasources).

Disclaimer: I'm Nutiteq developer.